# Is it worth it to craft the Alchemical Tome?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-equivalent-exchange

I have been playing a lot with equivalent exchange the last month or two (seriously, it was mid-August when I started messing with it, and I think I've logged over a hundred hours in there). By this point, I've accumulated a lot of the neat endgame stuff. I've been toying around with the idea of trying to craft the Alchemical Tome, to fully unlock the power of my Transmutation Tablet. I'm not sure that it's worth the amount of time it would take, though. It takes 152,732,278 EMC to craft the tablet, which is three fully-charged Klein Star Omegas.

Has anyone else actually crafted the Tome, so they could unlock the full Transmutation Tablet? Is it worth the time? I'm mostly curious about what items I could create that I don't already have access to through the normal game.

Comment: It's nice to be able to create any item, but it's also annoying because it makes it much harder to find the particular item you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alchemical Tome adds all items that have an EMC value to the Transmutation Table. There are no items that cannot be crafted that can be obtained through this method. Unless you have a lot of mods that include EMC values using the alchemical tome is only really used for adventure/survial maps that do not have all the items in them.

As a note. In equivalent exchange 3 all mod items will have a EMC value generated from crafting recipies, so it may become worth it.

Answer (score 1):

It does give you access to more rare items that are hard to aquire or find, such as mycellium. However the tablet only shows about 14 items, so it can become a nightmare to find the item you are after. I dare you to try and find mycellium with a alchemical tome upgraded tablet, you can't. Which sucks, because that was why I made it in the first place. Not worth it.